# Setting values persisting over python sessions

Tags: python, file-sharing

I'd like to define a constant in my script like that path to my Dropbox folder. Most my scripts will try to load some data of Dropbox which is shared among my PCs, but I find that between Mac and Ubuntu the prefix is different (`/Users/<user>/Dropbox` versus `/home/<user>/Dropbox`).

Is there a way to save this kind of information in some variable that will be loaded in each session such that I could have a global variable like DROPBOX (what would be a good convention, __DROPBOX__?) as path prefix to a file name, e.g. `fname = DROPBOX + "myfile.txt"`.

Kind of reminds of me defining this in one's `.Rprofile` which holds settings in `R`.

Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887798/saving-and-recovering-values-of-variables-between-executions

Comment: @user3757614 Bad example, I know pickling certainly is not the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the built in environment variables to get the path to the user home directory:

```
import os
print os.environ['HOME']
```

Which would solve your problem is a way that is more likely to remain stable if run on a new machine.

Comment: Excellent, knew there must have been something.

Comment: Then again, having to import os and use that long name is still not preferred. I guess I should just work with relative paths unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
os.path.expanduser('~/Dropbox')
```

or you can just try different alternatives:

```
dirs_to_try = ('/Users/Guido/Dropbox', '/home/Guido/Dropbox')
for path in dirs_to_try:
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        break
finally:
    print 'cannot find Dropbox directory'
    path = None
```

Comment: I mean... one way would be to make it a function globally, but then still I would basically want it to just be available in ANY python session, from the get-go. That's the problem in the first place.