# jupyter delete all variables after cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can I delete all variables in jupyter that are defined / created after a certain cell number?

My specific use case is that I will load some variables in the first few cells and I want to keep those variables, while I will experiment on the notebook.

I do not want to keep restarting or reseting the notebook as it takes time to load those variables. Instead I would like to "restart" from a certain cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford the memory and duplicate the variables, store "backup" variables using something like `copy.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy()` and create a cell were you reallocate original values to your variables from the backups.

You'll have run this cell to restore your values.

**see edit details below**

For illustration:

1. Store original values

```python
from copy import deepcopy

bckp_a = deepcopy(var_a)
bckp_b = deepcopy(var_b)

dir_bckp = deepcopy(dir())  # store defined variables defined at this point
```

2. Do you stuff

```python
var_a = some_func(var_a)
var_b = some_other_func(var_a)
var_c = some_value
```

3. Restore original values for preserved variables

```python
var_a = deepcopy(bckp_a)
var_b = deepcopy(bckp_b)
```

4. Delete newly created variables

```python
for var in dir():
    if var == 'dir_bckp':      # Note that it is a string
        continue                   # Preserve dir_bckp, very important.
    elif var not in dir_bckp:
        del globals()[var]     # Delete newly defined variables

>>> var_c
NameError: name 'var_c' is not defined
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you absolutely need to **delete** created variables, you can try a trick with `dir()` and `globals()`. But this is probably not good practice, so be cautious.

See changes above.

Note that there is also the option of [creating a restore point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887798/saving-and-recovering-values-of-variables-between-executions) using `Pickle`, but I'm not sure of the performance if some variables take time to load.

Comment: So with the backup variables, I am interested in knowing how that can help to delete other variables

Comment: Once variable values restored, re-run and garbage collector will do his job. If you really want to delete these variables, you can backup `dir()` and restore it. But this is a trick, I doubt it is good practice. I will explain in a edit.

Comment: @user113531: is it what you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry missed your reply. It is working, and doesn't sounds like a good practice to me as well. Would like to hear your idea on why it is not a good practice.