# Writing variables to and reading from a file in python(3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a small text based adventure with a friend. We are going to be creating different levels on different files. How would I write the variables created in level 1 and read them to have the name and exp for the next level?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568904/saving-the-state-of-a-program-to-allow-it-to-be-resumed

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: You might consider using a small database like sqlite.